# for loop going through index[0] twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

I am using the for loop to go through an array and add all the values together. Everything works but for some reason, it goes through index[0] twice (screenshot of the console attached).
Can someone please help? I only want to go through index[0] once.
I am working with javascript in react.

```js
ffunction getCo2consump(){
  var co2Consump =[]; //this needs to be updated to be the co2consump from db later
  //get consump from databse
  var combinedConsump = 0;
  var i;
  database
  .collection("Users")
    .doc(email)
    .collection("ChosenChallenge")
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        co2Consump.push(doc.data().Co2Consumption);
        for (i=0; i< co2Consump.length; i++){
          console.log("this is i", i);
          console.log("this is co2consump in loop", co2Consump[i]);
          console.log(typeof co2Consump[i]);
          combinedConsump = combinedConsump + co2Consump[i];
          console.log(typeof combinedConsump);

        }
      });
      console.log("this is co2Consump array", co2Consump)
      console.log("this is combined", combinedConsump)
      return combinedConsump;
})
}
```

Screenshot of the console
[image]

Comment: the snippet with the databse doesn't bring anything could you replace it with a sample output which the database would return.

Comment: Your output shows logging that is clearly not being done by any of the code shown ("this is i"). Please show the actual code, or better yet, a [mcve].

Comment: You have two loop one outside one inside when it run for 1 at time array have one value, then inner so so one element

Comment: Then 2time, 2nd push so two element. Remove the inner loop

Answer (score 2):

`for` loop is inside of the `forEach` loop, so it will set `i=0` for every one item in your collection.
You need to calculate your total CO2 consumption outside of `forEach`.

```
function getCo2consump(){
  var co2Consump =[]; //this needs to be updated to be the co2consump from db later
  //get consump from databse
  var combinedConsump = 0;
  var i;
  database
  .collection("Users")
    .doc(email)
    .collection("ChosenChallenge")
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        co2Consump.push(doc.data().Co2Consumption);
        }
      });
      co2Consump.forEach(e=>combinedConsump+e);
      console.log("this is co2Consump array", co2Consump)
      console.log("this is combined", combinedConsump)
      return combinedConsump;
})
}
```